# How can I recover a blockchain.info wallet without the wallet identifier or the mnemonic?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, e-wallet

My son made both of us each our own bitcoin wallet, and showed me how to use the faucets. With me being disabled and sometimes not being able to get out of bed because of pain; He thought it would give me something to do while he was at school all day.

So, I played with 3 or 4 of the faucets last week and at least 2 of them said they paid out Sat/Sun as long as you have at least 5500 Satoshi in their account, which I did.

So, I  wanted to see how much was in my wallet (and if the faucets actually paid out like they say they do) after the weekend. I went to Blockchain.info (where my son said he went to make/get the wallets) and tried to login. It has a place that asks for "Identifier" and in the box it says Identifier or Alias. Now I have he long Alphanumerical "number" which I am not sure whether that is an address or Identifier or what, but I tried putting that in the box and it says "Unknown Wallet identifier. Please check you entered it correctly" I know I entered it correctly bc I copied and pasted it the last time to make sure.

I know that on the other wallet (the one I an NOT using) my son remembered to write some sort of mnemonic device that is supposed to be for recovering the wallet if you lose the long string of letters and numbers? (I think) but not for this one. I do know the email address and password used to create the wallet, but it doesn't ask for either of those.

Also, I read through a few not so similar Questions and answers where they spoke of downloading the wallet, which I know for sure we DID NOT do. Is this something you have to do?

I can type the long alphanumerical number into the main page and see there has been 2 deposits totaling 0.00033813 BTC, so I know it's there. But, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Please, someone tell me how to access my wallet and what I am doing wrong.

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3):

Quick primer:

- The identifier is a dash separated lowercase bit of text, like `a32d0de4-818b-4aa3-...`

  It's specific to blockchain.info - other wallets use different systems. It was probably emailed to you.
- The mnemonic is a 17 word bit of text, like `skill course bleed oversize attempting lazer endure...`
- A bitcoin address looks like 175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W. A bitcoin address is not specific to blockchain.info. It's how you tell the faucet where to send the money. This is not what you use to log in.
- All of this is different from your email address or password.

Troubleshooting steps:

You need to get either the mnemonic or the identifier. The identifier was probably emailed to you by blockchain.info, so check there. If you get the mnemonic, you can recover the identifier on the login screen with the 'Recover Wallet' button. I think it's also possible to get the identifier by contacting blockchain.info support, but you need additional information.

Once you have the identifier and the password, you can log in.

> Also, I read through a few not so similar Questions and answers where they spoke of downloading the wallet, which I know for sure we DID NOT do. Is this something you have to do?

It's something you need to do for some wallets. Not blockchain.info, though.

Answer (score 0):

Three quick thoughts:

1. The identifier (the dash-separated string of lowercase text mentioned above) is typically sent to you in an email with the subject line: Welcome to My Wallet.
2. If you don't have the "Welcome to My Wallet" email, Blockchain.info will mail your identifier to the email address associated with your account if you follow these steps:

   - Point your web browser to: https://blockchain.info/wallet/#/login
   - Click on “View Options” in the lower right-hand corner of the login form
   - Click the option that says “I’ve lost my Wallet ID: Email me a reminder with my Wallet ID to my email address”
   - Select “Remind Me”
   - Enter the email address you used to create the wallet, fill out the “captcha” and submit the form

If you correctly identified the email address that you used to create your wallet, then Blockchain.info should email you the Wallet ID within a few minutes.

3. Finally, if you can get your Wallet ID, but you don't remember your password, you can find a systematic process to try to find your password in [this article](https://cryptoassetrecovery.com/blog/recover-lost-blockchain-password/).